# ListView doesn't scroll

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-listview

I have a horizontal `ListView` (shown in the image with list items a,b,c) that will not scroll, or rather, it does scroll - but one out of 10 or so swipes seems to make it scroll. I have also used a `FlatList` - same result. The ListView is on a [Interactable.View](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable), however I got rid of the [Interactable.View](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable) and it still didn't scroll. I've tested on a real ios device and a genymotion emulator and both had the same result. There are more items in the list than just a,b,c. There are 6 items in the list.

[image]

```
   import { StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList, ListView } from 'react-native'
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import {
      Button,
      Container
    } from 'native-base'

import { updateRegion } from './map.action'
import { OptimizedFlatList } from 'react-native-optimized-flatlist'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import { toggleMenu } from '../search-page/searchPage.action'
import mapStyle from './style'
import Interactable from 'react-native-interactable'
import { setSelectedShop } from '../search-results/searchResults.action'
import { updateHeight } from '../search-results/searchResultsPresenter.action'
import { getSelectedProduct } from './markers.selector'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  region: state.get('map').get('region'),
  markers: state.get('searchResults').get('products'),
  selectedProduct: getSelectedProduct(state),
  height: state.get('searchResultsPresenter').get('height')
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onRegionChange: (region) => {
    dispatch(updateRegion(region))
  },
  onToggleMenuClick: () => {
    dispatch(toggleMenu())
  },
  setSelectedShop: id => {
    dispatch(setSelectedShop(id))
  },
  updateHeight: height => {
    dispatch(updateHeight(height))
  }
})

class Map extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => { })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.selectedProduct) {
      let products = newProps.selectedProduct.products
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(products)
      })
    }
  }

  interactableView;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 }) }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.height)
    return (
      <Container>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.props.region}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this.props.onRegionChange}>
          {
            this.props.markers.map(marker => {
              return (
                <MapView.Marker
                  coordinate={marker.shop.coordinate}
                  title={marker.shop.name}
                  identifier={marker.shop.id.toString()}
                  onPress={e => {
                    console.log(e.nativeEvent)
                    this.interactableView.snapTo({ index: 0 })
                    this.props.setSelectedShop(marker.shop)
                    console.log(this.props.selectedProduct)
                  }}
                />
              )
            })
          }
        </MapView>

        <Button
          small
          icon
          style={mapStyle.toggleMenuButton}
          onPress={() => this.props.onToggleMenuClick()}>
          <Icon name="sliders" size={20} color="#FFFFFF" />
        </Button>

        <Interactable.View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            zIndex: 20,
            borderRadius: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#222222',
            padding: 30,
            paddingTop: 50
          }}
          verticalOnly={true}
          snapPoints={[{ y: this.props.height - 225 }, { y: this.props.height - 50 }]}
          initialPosition={{ y: this.props.height - 50 }}
          ref={view => this.interactableView = view}
          onLayout={(event) => {
            this.props.updateHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout.height)
          }}  >


          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 50 }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                position: 'absolute',
                top: -40,
                marginBottom: 20,
                textAlign: 'center',
                width: '100%'
              }}>
              {this.props.selectedProduct ? this.props.selectedProduct.shop.name : ''}
            </Text>
            <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              horizontal={true}
              style={{
                height: 200
              }}
              renderRow={(rowData)=> {
                console.log(rowData)
                return (
                  <View style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                    width: 100,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    margin: 0
                  }}>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{rowData.name}</Text>
                    <View style={{
                      zIndex: 15,
                      width: '100%',
                      height: '100%',
                      backgroundColor: 'red'
                    }}>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )
              }}
            />
          </View>



        </Interactable.View>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}



Map.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
}

Map.propTypes = {
  region: React.PropTypes.shape({
    latitude: React.PropTypes.number,
    longitude: React.PropTypes.number,
    latitudeDelta: React.PropTypes.number,
    longitudeDelta: React.PropTypes.number
  }).isRequired,
  height: React.PropTypes.number,
  updateHeight: React.PropTypes.func,
  setSelectedShop: React.PropTypes.func,
  selectedProduct: React.PropTypes.string,
  onRegionChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onToggleMenuClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  markers: React.PropTypes.array
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Map)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    zIndex: 3
  }
})
```

How do I get the listview to scroll with every swipe, rather than about 1 out of 10 swipes?

**Same thing happens when I use a ScrollView. So nothing can be swiped horizontally there. Even when removing the `interactable.view`**

Comment: I think it will work perfect in release mode.

Comment: @Codesingh unfortunately it didn't work in release mode. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Making `renderRow` return a `TouchableHighlight` instead of a `View` caused the list to be draggable with every touch and swipe. And finally, unessential to the answer, I switched from a `ListView` to a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) because `ListView` is going to be deprecated in the future. I felt it good to state that as at this point in time it isn't clear from the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) that `ListView` is becoming deprecated.